# How can I RSS subscribe to Ethereum address?

Tags: rss, blockchain, ethereum

Since everything is on-chain in Ethereum blockchain. Theoretically, each event is public visible and can be summed up as a block event. Is it possible to subscribe to events of non-contract addresses and create a feed page like RSS subscription?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but honestly, I have never seen integration with the RSS protocol.

However, writing your script in the programming language is very easy. The procedure is well documented in the official [geth documentation](https://goethereumbook.org/event-subscribe/): https://goethereumbook.org/event-subscribe/

I would use this as a reference for other languages.

There is one big problem for you. To subscribe to Ethereum, you need access to the Ethereum node to get events from it.

There are three options from the best to the worst (in my opinion).

1. You can use the API from parties that provide access to ethereum networks. Example of it is [INFURA](https://infura.io/), [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) and [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/). The huge disadventage is that requests are limited and you will use it very fast. Probably in minutes or hours.
2. You can create your own node connected to the Ethereum, but you need pretty fast computer/stable internet and 1TB SSD hard drive to keep it stable.
3. Find publicly available node. Usualy those nodes are not very stable and you will get ban soon. To discover ethereum nodes you can use [Shodan](https://www.shodan.io/). I have tried houndred times to use the public nodes to write my apps and those nodes are not stable. Each stable node is protected and does not allow to send any request to it...

If you need to read data from specific addresses you can use the [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis) - I love it as it is much easier than using the ETH API :)

Comment: See [ethereumnodes.com](https://ethereumnodes.com/) for software-as-a-service JSON-RPC options

Answer (score 1):

There is an opensource protocol named RSS3 dedicated to RSS service on blockchain.

Its third-party API accesses the Ethereum network and creates a feed of any ENS address. The protocol not only displays transactions of the ENS, but also identifies and filter different types of on-chain transactions.
(check how more on [RSS3 Docs](https://docs.rss3.io/docs/category/pregod) and its [Github](https://github.com/NaturalSelectionLabs/RSS3-PreGod-v0.4))

The feed can be generated to a standard XML format RSS file, or import the RSS URL or that address directly to any RSS reader.

Take ETH founder Vitalik's ENS address (vitalik.eth) for example.

1. Access RSS3.io and type in the ENS

enter vitalik.eth

2. Generate RSS file

Click the RSS icon on the right and get the RSS file:
https://rss3.io/rss/0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045/

3. Generate RSS URL

Go to https://rss3.io/manage and generate an RSS feed for an address/ENS.

Type in Vitalik.eth and get different types of RSS feed subscription:

All feeds: https://rss3.io/rss/vitalik.eth

These URLs should work in any RSS reader.